# Merlin (TV) Fanfic - Modern AU Merlin inherits Gaius house and Arthur renovates it

Tags: story-identification, fan-fiction, merlin-bbc

Looking for a Merlin fanfic based on the BBC series that’s been bugging me for a while as I’ve been reading into that area again.

It was an alternate universe modern AU with a Merlin/Arthur slash. Basically Merlin inherits a house from Gaius when he dies as he’s his mother’s uncle or something along those lines and after visiting with Arthur they decide to keep it despite it being in bad shape and Arthur will do the building work. I remember the house being described as quite grand and perhaps Victorian styled but definitely a period property and I’m almost certain it was set in the US.

In this fic I feel like Arthur was unemployed or was looking into a career change and that’s why he had time to do this, Merlin was something very time consuming I’m leaning towards student doctor but I could be wrong. Arthur does most of the work himself, restores the furniture, sands, paints etc room by room. They live in a caravan on the drive way for most of the fic until the house is ready if I remember right.

They were operating on a budget as I recall also and it ends with Arthur completing the house the progress of which Merlin hasn’t been aware off outside of helping to choose fittings etc.

It wasn’t a particularly long fic I feel about 10-20 thousand words maybe but I recall it being very sweet and I’d quite like to read it again. It was either Ao3 or FanFiction.Net but I’m leaning towards the latter as I’ve been reading extensively on the other for a few weeks and found nothing.